# Facebook SDK in Storyboard?

Tags: iphone, facebook, storyboard

Is it possible to use the Facebook SDK 3.0 with iPhone storyboard? I can't find any tutorials using storyboard. If it is possible, do you have any tutorials?

Answer (score 1):

There is a sample application that you can go through that shows you how to use storyboards. This uses the Facebook SDK 3.1.

https://github.com/fbsamples/ios-social-cafe

It shows logging in with Facebook, publishing using Open Graph, the friend and place picker, and also deep linking.

Comment: Dead link. Goes to 404.

Answer (score 0):

had the same problem, me and another dev figured it out ourselves and built a dumb simple solution:

https://github.com/kincade71/Face-Code-X